# Android how to know precise phone state (alerting and Talk)?

Tags: android, state, phone-call

We know there're IDLE and OFFHOOK state for caller, but for my app, we need to know the state of alerting and talking.

Alerting means the ring tone ring and talking means callee answers the call.
  We know the framework and native Phone APP already have this information.

However, it needs  READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE or MODIFY_PHONE_STATE  permission, but only manufacturer can have the permissions. How can we work around or hack to get this kind of information(alerting and talking of caller)?

Of course, we also hope users can download our app from google play if the hack is achieved.

We checked the Phone App source code, it calls enforceCallingOrSelfPermission to check the permission before get the information. It seems impossible to get the information because Google protects it on purpose.

What do you think? We almost give it up.

Comment: In fact, I need to know the duration  of alerting state of caller and callee. I can't find any way to get this  without permission of READ_PRECISE_PHONE_STATE or MODIFY_PHONE_STATE.